# ASP.Net MVC 4 Load css File dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website on which there is a need for customization, which means i need to change the theme of the page depending on the option selected by the user. I need to know how to change the css file which is rendered through Layout.cshtml according to the users selection.

These are the two css file in my layout.cshtml

@Styles.Render("~/Content/style1.css") -> Theme 1
@Styles.Render("~/Content/style2.css") -> Theme 2

I have assign two links to click in order to change the css file in my home webpage(Link 1-Theme 1,Link 2- Theme 2) but i don't know how to change it.

My initial idea was to have two links and when the link is pressed it will be sent to a controller from which it will be redirected to the page after selecting the appropriate css file from layout.cshtml depending on the users selection using an if condition, i guess that idea is not possible.

Please let me know the best way to do this since i need to implement this solution in my website soon.

Comment: lol, you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SGHE2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a query string parameter that sets `whichStyleFlavor`:

```
@{
    string whichStyleFlavor = "1";
    ... some logic to check what they requested and change whichStyleFlavor
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/style" + whichStyleFlavor + ".css")
```

Or you can do it on the client, by switching the CSS  tag.

From [here](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1253):

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```